# Batch script: goto was unexpected. using find xyz file.log && goto pass || goto fail

Tags: batch-file, adb, goto

I have a very weird error from my batch script.
Although the code uses Android Debugging Bridge, I'm sure it's an error related to cmd as opposed to adb.
So, basically if anyone cares, the script just checks root access. Here's a sniplet of the code:

```
@echo off
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb shell "su" >check.log 2>&1
adb kill-server
"%windir%\system32\find.exe" "#" check.log && goto pass || goto fail
:fail
echo No root access!
pause
:pass
echo Root access detected!
pause
```

The output for this is:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port XXXX *
* daemon started successfully *
* server not running *
---------- CHECK.LOG
goto was unexpected at this time
```

And the window closes automatically.

If I run it in a command window by manually typing the commands, this is what I get:

```
J:\tools>adb kill-server

J:\tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port XXXX *
* daemon started successfully *

J:\tools>adb shell su >check.log 2>&1

J:\tools>"%windir%\system32\find.exe" "#" check.log && echo pass || echo fail

---------- CHECK.LOG
fail
```

Can anyone think of a solution? I tried to do it like this:

```
@echo off
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb shell "su" >check.log 2>&1
adb kill-server
SET tr=0
"%windir%\system32\find.exe" "#" check.log >nul && SET tr=1 || SET tr=0
if "%tr%"=="1" goto pass
if "%tr%"=="0" goto fail
```

I still get the error for goto. :/
I'm puzzled, I have used other such statements before.
Thanks for reading through! :)

Oh, system32 is sometimes not present in path & as this is being made for others to use, I need to use %windir%\system32\

Comment: That line worked for me absolutely fine. If you posted a complete batch script, then I can see no issue with it. Could it be that this script is called by another script? And so maybe the error occurs in the other script.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your `find` line and it worked fine for me. Try using `%errorlevel%` as a workaround, which also works fine on my pc

```
find "#" check.log
if %errorlevel%==0 goto pass
if %errorlevel%==1 goto fail
```

*Note: You don't need to specify the full path to `find`, as `system32` is in the `PATH` variable.*

Hope this helps!